# How can I use special characters as exposing in string

Tags: java, regex, string, character-encoding

How can I use special characters as exposing in string variable like ⁽¹⁾ ? 
In order to have : `String str="⁽¹⁾";`

Comment: What does this have to do with regular expressions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any character other than double-quote and backslash and newline characters, you can use `\uABCD` style escapes.

For a non-supplemental codepoints, like ⁽¹⁾,

```
String str = "\u207d\u00b9\u207e";
// Prints true when javac's source encoding matches the file encoding.
System.out.println(str.equals("⁽¹⁾"));
```

should work.

For strings with supplemental code-points, first UTF-16 encode the string, then turn each UTF-16 code-unit into a `\UABCD` style escape sequence.

Comment: `+1` for the encoding tip. In DOS (where I was trying it) I had to use `javac -encoding utf8 Main.java`

Answer (score 2):

Use the unicode string for ⁽¹⁾ (U+207D U+00B9 U+207E). To match "⁽¹⁾" you'd do:

```
Pattern.compile("\u207D\u00B9\u207E")
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to match these characters you can use this class (⑴ to ⒇):

```
[\\u2474-\\u2487]
```